# Flutter animation text field on search page

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-animation

I am create custom search page. When this page is opened, hamburger menu is hide and search text field change size instantly. how to make it happen smoothly?

[image]

Now i make this code

```
class DefaultAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(56.0);

  @override
  _DefaultAppBarState createState() => _DefaultAppBarState ();

}

class _DefaultAppBarState extends State<DefaultAppBar> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  double textWidth = 300.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var future = new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), ()=>setState(() {
      textWidth = 400.00;
    }));

    return Stack(
        children: [
      Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,

          // ...
          title:AnimatedContainer (
            duration: Duration (milliseconds: 500),
            width: loginWidth,

//            color: Colors.red,
            child:  TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              // ...
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,color: Colors.grey),
                hintText: 'Search something ...',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,


//                border: InputBorder.none,
//                hintText: "My Custom Search Label", // KEY PROP
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // KEY PROP
              ),
            ),
          ),


            ),

)


    ]
    );
  }
}
```

And get this result

[image]

Work, but not very smoothly and how to calculate start and finish for textWidth  automatically and how make back animation like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/mWpdsouLi4csptKb7

Comment: explain more !!!

Comment: do like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/WyS8TWQLhfHZqmK5A

Answer (score 0):

1. To make the hamburger icon disappear, wrap it with a `Visability` widget:

```
Visibility(
  child: ...,
  visible: !_searchIsExpanded,
),
```

2. To animate the search bar, wrap it with `AnimatedContainer` and a `Expanded` widgets.

**EDIT**

By the added screenshot, it seems that you don't want the hamburger icon to disappear, therefor everything should be wraped with a `Stack` widget, and change the width of the based on if if pressed, the `AnimatedContainer` would take care of the smooth animation.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a stack if the width of the icon is set to 0. He just needs to toggle with width back and forth between 0 and maxWidth for the icon

Comment: that is correct if he want the icon to disappear, but in the attached animation the icon does not disappear, the search bur just covers it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **searchDelegate** ,  you need to create a new class that extends the SearchDelegate class.
Hope that is the correct answer to you qst; 
this is an example of class that you should create :

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.length < 3) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Search term must be longer than two letters.",
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    }

    //Add the search term to the searchBloc. 
    //The Bloc will then handle the searching and add the results to the searchResults stream.
    //This is the equivalent of submitting the search term to whatever search service you are using
    InheritedBlocs.of(context)
        .searchBloc
        .searchTerm
        .add(query);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        //Build the results based on the searchResults stream in the searchBloc
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: InheritedBlocs.of(context).searchBloc.searchResults,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Result>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "No Results Found.",
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              var results = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: results.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var result = results[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(result.title),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is called everytime the search term changes. 
    // If you want to add search suggestions as the user enters their search term, this is the place to do that.
    return Column();
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i have this class but i try to do animation like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/WyS8TWQLhfHZqmK5A